# Tracking redistricting in a SQL database

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

I'm working on a project that tracks health data at three levels:

`Country -> Region -> District`

Due to redistricting, there are times when a district splits into two or more districts or two or more districts combine into a single district.

One of the reporting goals with the database is to be able to track data over a period of 10 or more years. At the district level, it is important for staff to be able to see the history of their district, regardless of whether it exists in the same state that it did years earlier.

For example, let's assume we have the following and that for each year, we have a valid population number for each district, along with some disease surveillance data. In this example, `DA` splits into `DC` and `DD` in 2010 and `DC` and `DE` combine in 2013.

```
2008: DA, DB
2009: DA, DB
2010: DA -> (DC,DD), DB
2011: DC, DD, DB -> (DE, DF)
2012: DC, DD, DE, DF
2013: (DC,DE) -> DG, DD, DF
2014: DG, DD, DF
2015: DG, DD, DF
```

At face value, it seems like using a graph of some sort would be the best way to track it.

How would you go about tracking these changes in a SQL database such that one could attempt to look at the history, for example, of district `DG` over the period of 2008-2015?

*(I know that DF doesn't exist in 2008, but using the population data, we can back calculate numbers to approximate the prevalence of a particular disease in the area it covers...)*

Comment: I would look into DB2's SQL:2011 temporal features

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan +1 for the interesting features, though after reading the docs on it, i don't think they solve OP's problem at all.

Comment: SQL Temporal lets you store different data in the same rows over time, and query it by period, while maintaining foreign keys.

Comment: I understand. You can extract a point in time, any point in time. But i dont see how you can easily extract a branching tree of the changes, as he describes, without making a lot of queries and having the application handle the logic.

Answer (score 1):

It always depends on what the final expected result should contain, but based on what is given in the question, i'd probably make each heath-data entry relate to a district id, and stamp on a timestamp for each heath-data record.

So when DA splits into DC and DD, 2 new districts are created with new unique id's.
Also, District name shouldnt be unique. So when DC merge with DD  and becomes DA again, DA is again a completely new entity with a new id.

To track the old district, i'd have a table, as such:

> ```
> district_history_relation
> ---------------------------
> district_id | old_district_id | timestamp
> ```

So lets say DA = 1. It splits and becomes DC = 2 and DD = 3. To track this, we add

```
INSERT INTO district_history_relation (district_id, old_district_id) VALUES (2,1);
INSERT INTO district_history_relation (district_id, old_district_id) VALUES (3,1);
```

When they merge again and become DA = 4, we go

```
INSERT INTO district_history_relation (district_id, old_district_id) VALUES (4,2);
INSERT INTO district_history_relation (district_id, old_district_id) VALUES (4,3);
```

The data is saved as

```
INSERT INTO health_data (district_id,data,timestamp) VALUES (4,'whatever',NOW());
```

Then you have full joinability to the district as a unique entity, a nice district_history_relation to query foreach district change. If you expect that the "history-tree" will be traversed often, then i'd add a "cache table" to the district table, since traditional RDBMS dont handle real tree queries.
Like so:

> ```
> district_tree_cache
> --------------------- 
> district_id | tree
> ```

```
INSERT INTO district_tree_cache (district_id,tree) VALUES (4,'1|2,3|4');
```

Which can then be split on "|" and will contain each "step" in the history. This will be joinable, so you can do it in 1 query. Cache would need to be recalculated everytime the disctrict changes, of course.

Comment: Thanks for this. The problem is slightly more complicated because I just found out that the regions split and are redrawn, too. Theoretically, the countries can split, too (Sudan -> Sudan + South Sudan). However, this is a great starting point.

Comment: @Clay good to hear. The splitting of regions can be done in the exact same way, but in region_history_relation instead. And as each health-data items is related to a district, each district could be related to a region, giving you the exact same way of handling both levels.